# How to edit/replace single file in SFDC static resources?

Tags: salesforce, static-resource

I have a static resource zip file in SFDC that contains images and css files used by Visualforce pages. How do you replace just a single image with a new one from the resource zip file? Do I need to upload the entire zip file again with the new image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update files which you need in zip archive (which contain all files for current static resource) and upload it again to SF.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You need to upload the updated Zip file again into static Resource..No other way as of now.

[HelpLink](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_static_resources_edit.htm&language=en_US)